# FLASH_MODE_TORCH in CameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax, camera-flash

I am trying to keep the flash on all time by setting flash to FLASH_MODE_TORCH in CameraX in my app. But, I could not find this flash mode for cameraX. Is this mode not available in cameraX? If not, is there any alternative to keep my flash on whole time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to enable the torch by calling [`CameraControl.enableTorch(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl#enableTorch(boolean)), it internally sets the capture request's flash mode to `FLASH_MODE_TORCH`.

If the camera does not have a flash unit (i.e. [`CameraInfo.hasFlashUnit()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraInfo#hasFlashUnit()) returns false), calling `enableTorch(true)` will be no-op.

```
final Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(...);
final CameraInfo cameraInfo = camera.getCameraInfo();
final CameraControl cameraControl = camera.getCameraControl();

if (cameraInfo.hasFlashUnit()) {
    cameraControl.enableTorch(true); // You can listen to this future to handle errors
}
```

Comment: The proposed method does not work for me.